# Який український відповідник до російського "полотенцесушитель"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Окремого слова СУМ не містить.

[Інтернет-магазин "Розетка"](http://bt.rozetka.com.ua/ua/163904/c163904/) пропонує варіант ***`сушарка для рушників`***.

СУМ дає такі значення для ***`сушарка`***

[СУША́РКА](http://sum.in.ua/s/susharka), и, жін.

1. **Пристрій, прилад для сушіння чого-небудь, видалення вологи з чогось**. *Юлка визбирала яблука з-під дерев.. За кілька кроків від неї злегка диміла сушарка* (Михайло Томчаній, Жменяки, 1964, 141); *З метою поліпшення якості сульфату на другому боці цеху пущено сушильну установку. Встановлюються сушарки і на першому блоці* (Робітнича газета, 23.I 1961, 3); С*кладану сушарку для грибів найкраще виготовити з відходів бляхи товщиною до 1 мм* (Знання та праця, 9, 1971, 31); *Основні машини для сушіння насінного і продовольчого зерна — сушарки шахтного типу* (Хлібороб України, 1, 1969, 25).
2. **Приміщення, признач. для сушіння чого-небудь.** *За будиночком тяглися довгі амбари, сушарка, винний погріб* (Юрій Збанацький, Таємниця.., 1971, 387); *Десь тут має стояти сушарка, в яку восени звозять тютюн* (Юрій Мушкетик, Чорний хліб, 1960, 168); *Для повної переробки продуктів садівництва передбачено в найближчі роки розширити виноробню і збудувати сушарку* (Колгоспник України, II, 1960, 7).

Ніби й нормальний варіант, та, як на мене, дещо немилозвучний.

Зустрічаються ще [рушниковисушувач](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C&oq=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.5978j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83%D1%88%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%87) та, рідше, [рушникоосушувач](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C&oq=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.5978j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D1%88%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%87). Утім, ні ***`висушувача`***, ні ***`осушувача`*** в СУМ немає.

Тож чи є якийсь усталений відповідник, чи кому як до вподоби?

Comment: На olx та на інших сайтах оголошень невимушено використовують слово рушникосушка. Ми в родині це теж так називаємо, але я не певен, чи це "офіційний" термін, чи просто розмовний.

https://www.olx.ua/uk/list/q-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0/

Comment: @wrench, я зустрічала *сушка*, але воно мені ще кострубатіше, аніж *сушарка*. На Полтавщині *сушка* - синонім  до *сушні*, *сухофруктів*. А ще асоціюється з бубликами. Такі ж значення, в доповнення до *процесу сушіння*, дає й СУМ для [*сушка*](http://sum.in.ua/s/sushka).

Comment: сушка для рушників, від слова СУШИТИ

Answer (score 5):

[Російсько-український народний сучасний словник](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on):

> **Полотенцесушитель** – сушни́к, суша́рка, суши́ло, су́шка, (*разг., образн.*) змії́вка.

Вдома коли нема неоднозначності кажу *сушарка*, коли є то *рушникосушарка*.

Answer (score 0):

Сушник. З мовної практики. Цю штуку в Київській області називають "сушник".